# Which is the most popular non-Jōyō kanji?

Tags: kanji

Basically, a trivia question that someone could answer with a script.

What is the statistically most popular *kanji* in Japanese texts not in the *jōyō* list? Was it ever considered for inclusion? Is it popular due to names only or used in compounds? Same for *hyōgai kanji*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's looking for a statistic, not addressing something specific about the Japanese language.

Comment: A minor point but perhaps 'highest frequency' is a more accurate term than 'popular', assuming you are asking about statistical relativity between kanji characters.

Comment: @istrasci I think it is a reasonable question.

Comment: @kandyman:  That's fine if you think that.  That's why closing questions is decided by voting and not just one person.  And I don't think it's unreasonable; just off-topic.

Answer (score 19):

Here are the top 30ish non-jouyou, non-jinmei kanji from several frequency databases. I compiled these a while ago for my own curiosity and don't readily have references to the source data (other than the excel file I made).

The kanji in each list (except for the last one) are in descending order of frequency with the most frequent first.

> Aozora Bunko
>
> 學處爺體當厭妾叩顏覗會對聲嘘歸掻發鼠儘變呆數噛慾狐關經睨呟
>
> Newspaper
>
> 嶽渕澤涌槿舛趙尹鉾靱妓聯諫潘舘銚筧苫炳粕桓橿荊姦薮扮捏頸鮫禱
>
> Twitter
>
> 嘘艸垢澤奢餃糞卍叩彡琲罒噛呟騙咳舐罠芒炒灬贅苫遽煽乁洒覗痒揉
>
> Wikipedia
>
> 澤學牝魏牌鐵曰欅祀叩渕濱讐癌趙輌舘嘘苫狗吊譚站讀綬廠姦薇憑罠
>
> Top 50 Jinmei from Newspaper
>
> 伊晋幌之也鵬菅彦阿弘圭智浩龍笠菱旭桐宏嶋柏李祐昌萩函遼嘉敦筑吾栗尖輔奄亮佑幡篠峯淳翔俣蔭稀堺磐毅乃哉
>   (EDIT: These were completely incorrect before the edit. I skipped part of the data when copying.)
>
> These are the ones that appear in more than one list (so they are probably the most useful)
>
> 澤嘘姦罠覗叩呟噛學渕舘苫趙

Comment: Wow, some of those, especially in the bottom list, are so common it's hard to believe they were never added to the jōyō kanji.

Comment: I don't know many kanji, but that 學 is simply variant of a Joyo one, isn't it? It's basically how it's rendered in Chinese Traditional.

Comment: @Wilson Yeah, it's actually listed on [the jōyō kanji chart](http://www.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/sisaku/joho/joho/kijun/naikaku/pdf/joyokanjihyo_20101130.pdf) as a 旧字体.

Comment: I'm surprised so many common kanji are not in the Joyo list :o

Comment: Nice idea to split them by genre! 艸 among other Twitter ones will be for making 顔文字 smileys ( *´艸｀)

Comment: Did you distinguish kanji used for names and toponyms from kanji for common words here?

Comment: @stop-cran The listings omit the Jinmeiyou kanji but are not processed in any other way as far as I know. I doubt that place names were accounted for given that each listing originally began with the kanji used to write dates. I'd expect that those would have been accounted for differently if the data had been post-processed at all. (The first thing I'd have done if I had compiled the data would have been to omit anything that looked like a date).

Answer (score 14):

Using the Joyo kanji from [here](https://imabi.net/joyokanjilist.htm) and the frequency list from [here](https://kanjicards.org/kanji-list-by-freq.html), I was able to generate this list (ordered by frequency):

> 伊 智 弘 彦 阿 李 浩 菱 煕 宏 幌 之 曽 梶 昌 靖 渕 也 旭 磯 孜 盧 笠 聡 曙 趙 筑 萩 栗 嘉 篠 菅 俣 淵 辰 霞 柏 辻 淳 荻 嶋 鳩 柴 桂 晋 晃 桐 鷹 猪 紘 庄 敦 磐 祐 鵬 亘 鄭 芦 龍 笹 柿 釧 綾 釜 毅 嶌 稔 函 鴨 樋 楊 駿 亮
>   吾 椿 圭 蓮 倶 堺 呆 窪 雀 畠 瑞 伍 蘭 蒲 秦 茅 輔 粕 冨 湘 椎 灘 堰 獅 姜 郁 鷲 楠 芥 其 玲 翔 肇 榎 劉 幡 諏 亨 嶺 喬 崔 琵 琶 聯 蘇 寅 乃 洲 樽 樺 槙 薩 巌 淀 麹 賭 睦 胡 峻 炒 屏 槻 蝶 梁 琢 箕 芭 逗 苫 楢 蕉 兜 琉
>   朋 姑 烏 僑 奄 遼 橘 漱 桧 宋 苑 巽 杜 藝 欣 魏 篇 此 峯 巴 禎 菩 檜 稜 牟 榊 錫 荏 倭 廟 銚 斐 魁 薮 鴻 於 赳 逢 凧 鵜 庵 葵 萬 禄 孟 鴈 狼 尖 翫 嶽 尭 卿 已 巳 暢 粟 燕 綴 埴 魯 牡 芹 杏 迦 鳳 馨 蔭 焉 慧 祇 鷺 彬 袴
>   匡 苅 讃 尹 欽 湛 狐 鴎 瀋 挺 嵯 雁 佃 綜 狛 壷 橿 翠 鮎 播 榛 帖 桶 惣 鞍 蔦 萱 梯 雫 絆 湊 隼 舵 渚 珂 煥 稀 癌 峨 嘘 旛 篭 芙 皐 雛 娼 篆 鮫 惟 牌 宕 喧 佑 蒋 樟 耀 黛 櫛 渥 濡 槍 襄 惇 蛋 脩 笘 宍 甫 壕 嬉 囃 蒼 簗
>   峙 粥 舘 銕 鄒 蜷 暉 捧 只 箏 檀 鵠 凱 彗 諌 樫 噂 牝 梓 洛 醍 砦 丑 笏 蕨 噺 抒 隈 叶 汐 絢 叩 朔 蔡 鍾 仇 伽 夷 瞑 杭 寓 黎 坐 鍼 塙 冴 葦 礒 咸 萌 饗 歪 偲 韮 漕 杵 薔 膠 允 眞 蒙 蕃 呑 碓 茗 瀕 蒔 鯉 竪 瘤 澤 溥 遥
>   或 矩 厦 冤 舜 侠 贅 杖 汪 猷 瑛 搜 曼 彪 撚 噛 卯 桝 撫 喋 溢 闊 藏 浙 彭 淘 剃 揃 綺 徘 巷 竿 蟹 袁 舩 茜 凌 厨 犀 簑 皓 甦 洸 毬 檄 姚 蛭 叢 椙 轟 贋 洒 貰 儲 緋 鯛 蓼 甕 喘 怜 溜 邑 鉾 碧 燈 瓜 哺 槌 啄 穣 嗜 偕 酉
>   蹄 頚 胚 牢 糞 悌 吊 楕 鮭 詫 鱒 轍 醤 惚 廣 藁 柚 舛 縞 謳 杞 鱗 釘 弛 狸 壬 硯 蝦

[Link to the script](https://gist.github.com/encody/8e2a126520001cbf81af668f6e5df05b).

This does not answer all of your questions but it could be a good start.

Comment: I suppose 琵 and 琶 nowadays are mostly used to refer a lake 琵琶湖. Anyway, apparently there are much more rare kanji in various names.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be exactly what you are looking for, but here there is a list of Jinmeiyo kanji (kanjis used for names which arent joyo kanji) listed by frequency. I noticed the second in the list is the first in one of the lists here.

> 之 伊 阿 乃 彦 智 紗 弘 祐 也 莉 嘉 巳 宏 龍 昌 浩 佑 吾 嶋 輔 栗 玖 茉 庄 幡 李 亮 笠 桂 晃 辻 眞 哉 冨 猪 笹 耶 淵 淳 磯 杏 慧 峯 萌 旭 伽 廣 鷹 菅 丞 埜 窪 惟 靖 萩 柴 篠 瑞 幌 國 綾 圭 嵯 甫 玲 芦 郁 俣 蓮 洲 柚 聡 柏 瑛 蘭 辰 允 峨 暢 楠 嶺 樋 伍 翔 侑 庵 琉 朋 畠 爾 鴨 紘 桐 敦 惠 蒲 梶 葵 鵜

[Jinmeiyo Kanji by frequency](https://www.kanshudo.com/collections/jinmeiyo_kanji)

Full list on the link